# How to copy data from one part of a table to another where certain vaules on that table are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically lets say `table1` looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT|TITLE

ABC    |HELLO
DEF    |GOODBYE 
GHI    |SOMETIMES
```

and `table2` like this:

```
ACCOUNT|TITLE

ABC    |MAIN
DEF    |MAIN
GHI    |MAIN
```

How do I set the title of the second table to the title of the table one, corresponding with the account code being the same?

Hope this makes sense :)

I want table 2 to look like this

```
ACCOUNT|TITLE

ABC    |HELLO
DEF    |GOODBYE 
GHI    |SOMETIMES
```

There are more rows and columns on the real table which is why i cant just copy one table and stick it on the second one.

Comment: It does not make sense.  Edit your question and provide the resulting data that you want.

Comment: `DROP TABLE table1; CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM table2;`

Comment: Putting this in: 
update D_NAMEBANKINFO join M_account on D_namebankinfo.account = M_account.account set D_NAMEBANKINFO.title = M_ACCOUNT.title
Getting this out:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want `update` with a `join`:

```
update table2 t2 join
       table1 t1
       on t2.account = t1.account
    set t2.title = t1.title;
```

Comment: So that will turn the title of ABC on table 2, from MAIN to HELLO, DEF's title on table 2 from MAIN to GOODBYE, ect?

Comment: @Steve101 . . . This should update the names in `table2` to match the corresponding names in `table1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT ignore INTO tab1 ('col1_', 'col2_') SELECT 'col1','col2' FROM tab2
```